# MySQL multiple joins with multiple conditions and ignore row based on other rows

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query that will show me all of the robot_partners I could possibly team up with to attack a specific robot. [image: Database Graph]

So given the above image,

Case 1: I need to be able to see that,
Kris controls Wall-E, Kris and Wall-E target R2D2 and that Mike controls Bender, and Mike and Bender target R2D2 as well, and that Wall-E and Bender are partners.  This would indicate that Kris and Mike would be good teammates to attack R2D2.

Case 2: I also need to be able to see that,
Kris controls Wall-E, Kris and Wall-E target GlaDOS and that Bender targets GlaDOS, and Bender is a Partner of Wall-E.  In this case there is no person that controls Bender and also targets GlaDOS, meaning it would be a good for me to find a person that controls Bender who will target GlaDOS with me.

Case 3: I also need to be able to see that,
Kris controls Wall-E, Kris and Wall-E target Rosie.  Wall-E and Bender are partners but Bender does not target Rosie.

I do NOT care about the fact that Wall-E targets Optimus Prime, because Kris does not target Optimus prime.

Now, if you stayed with me this long, I have that query written to a point where I can just so INSERT SELECT into my table and have my application do a little clean up after it reads from that table before passing the result off to the user.  I need help in getting it that last little bit so the application doesnt need to do anything besides format that result.

This is my query as it stands right now,

```
SELECT DISTINCT pt.person_id AS person_1, rt.robot_1 AS robot_1, rt.robot_2 AS target, rp.robot_2 AS robot_2, IFNULL(pt2.person_id, 0) AS person_2
FROM robot_partners AS rp
JOIN robot_targets AS rt ON (rp.robot_1 = rt.robot_1)
LEFT JOIN robot_targets AS rt2 ON (rt.robot_2 = rt2.robot_2 And rp.robot_2 = rt2.robot_1)
JOIN people AS p ON (p.robot_id = rt.robot_1)
JOIN person_targets AS pt ON (p.person_id = pt.person_id And pt.robot_id = rt.robot_2)
LEFT JOIN people AS p2 ON (rt2.robot_1 = p2.robot_id)
LEFT JOIN person_targets AS pt2 ON (p2.person_id = pt2.person_id And rt2.robot_2 = pt2.robot_id)
ORDER BY pt.person_id, rt.robot_1, rt.robot_2, rp.robot_2;
```

This query produces output like this,

```
|person_1 | robot_1 | target | robot_2 | person_2 |
|   1     |    1    |   3    |     2   |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   3    |     2   |    2     |
|   1     |    1    |   3    |     11  |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   4    |     2   |    3     |
|   1     |    1    |   4    |     2   |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   4    |     11  |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   5    |     2   |    3     |
|   1     |    1    |   5    |     2   |    4     |
|   1     |    1    |   5    |     2   |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   5    |     11  |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   6    |     2   |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   6    |     11  |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   7    |     2   |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   7    |     11  |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   8    |     2   |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   8    |     11  |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   9    |     2   |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   9    |     11  |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   12   |     2   |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   12   |     11  |    5     |
|   2     |    2    |   3    |     1   |    1     |
|   3     |    2    |   4    |     1   |    1     |
|   4     |    2    |   5    |     1   |    1     |
|   5     |    11   |   12   |     1   |    1     |
```

It relies on DISTINCT to remove a bunch of duplicates that I cant figure out how to remove by rearranging the query.  It also returns a row with a 0 person_2 when there is also a row with a person_2 id for the exact same stream of connections up to that point.

Ex:

```
|person_1 | robot_1 | target | robot_2 | person_2 |
|   1     |    1    |   5    |     2   |    4     |
|   1     |    1    |   5    |     2   |    0     |
```

In this case I do not care about the row with person_2 = 0 because the row with person_2 = 4 is there, and they have the same path (1,1,5,2,X).

I cant use a sub query ORDER BY DESC/GROUP BY to get rid of it because when this situation happens,

```
|person_1 | robot_1 | target | robot_2 | person_2 |
|   1     |    1    |   5    |     2   |    3     |
|   1     |    1    |   5    |     2   |    4     |
|   1     |    1    |   5    |     2   |    0     |
```

I need to be able to see that person 3 and 4 have the connection and using GROUP BY to get rid of this information.

However I cant just ignore all the rows where person_2 = 0 because I need to be able to know when Case 2 applies.

As for why person_2 is converted from NULL to 0, that is because the table this data gets stored in, has a primary key that involves all 5 columns and the PK can not have NULL.  I also can not make it just a Unique key because then when I do INSERT INTO SELECT... it would continually add duplicate rows because NULL != NULL.  Also all 5 of them columns have Foreign key constraints to their respective tables.  The reason 0 works is because I have a Dummy person 0 in the people table.

So my ideal output would look like this,

```
|person_1 | robot_1 | target | robot_2 | person_2 |
|   1     |    1    |   3    |     2   |    2     |
|   1     |    1    |   3    |     11  |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   4    |     2   |    3     |
|   1     |    1    |   4    |     11  |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   5    |     2   |    4     |
|   1     |    1    |   5    |     2   |    3     |
|   1     |    1    |   5    |     11  |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   6    |     2   |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   6    |     11  |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   7    |     2   |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   7    |     11  |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   8    |     2   |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   8    |     11  |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   9    |     2   |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   9    |     11  |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   12   |     2   |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   12   |     11  |    5     |
|   2     |    2    |   3    |     1   |    1     |
|   3     |    2    |   4    |     1   |    1     |
|   4     |    2    |   5    |     1   |    1     |
|   5     |    11   |   12   |     1   |    1     |
```

With these 3 rows having been removed from the result.

```
|   1     |    1    |   3    |     2   |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   4    |     2   |    0     |
|   1     |    1    |   5    |     2   |    0     |
```

Play area with everything setup. Similar to sqlfiddle.

http://rextester.com/MQCZX67915

Here are all the tables used in this example, and I have provided a rextester link also. The code to generate all of this is also in the rextester link.  I would have done sqlfiddle but it refused to run the queries.

Thanks for any help or ideas.

People:

```
+-----------+--------+----------+
| person_id |  name  | robot_id |
+-----------+--------+----------+
|         1 | Kris   |        1 |
|         2 | Mike   |        2 |
|         3 | Sue    |        2 |
|         4 | Dora   |        2 |
|         5 | Walter |       11 |
+-----------+--------+----------+
```

Robots:

```
+----------+----------------+
| robot_id |      name      |
+----------+----------------+
|        1 | Wall-E         |
|        2 | Bender         |
|        3 | R2D2           |
|        4 | Data           |
|        5 | HAL 9000       |
|        6 | GlaDOS         |
|        7 | ASIMO          |
|        8 | The Terminator |
|        9 | Rosie          |
|       10 | Optimus Prime  |
|       11 | The Iron Giant |
|       12 | Clank          |
+----------+----------------+
```

robot_partners:

```
+------------------+---------+---------+
| robot_partner_id | Robot_1 | Robot_2 |
+------------------+---------+---------+
|                1 |       1 |       2 |
|                2 |       2 |       1 |
|                3 |       1 |      11 |
|                4 |      11 |       1 |
+------------------+---------+---------+
```

person_targets:

```
+------------------+-----------+----------+
| person_target_id | person_id | robot_id |
+------------------+-----------+----------+
|                1 |         1 |        3 |
|                2 |         1 |        4 |
|                3 |         1 |        5 |
|                4 |         1 |        6 |
|                5 |         1 |        7 |
|                6 |         1 |        8 |
|                7 |         1 |        9 |
|                8 |         1 |       12 |
|                9 |         2 |        3 |
|               10 |         3 |        4 |
|               11 |         4 |        5 |
|               12 |         5 |       12 |
|               13 |         3 |        5 |
+------------------+-----------+----------+
```

robot_targets:

```
+-----------------+---------+---------+
| robot_target_id | Robot_1 | Robot_2 |
+-----------------+---------+---------+
|               1 |       1 |       3 |
|               2 |       1 |       4 |
|               3 |       1 |       5 |
|               4 |       1 |       6 |
|               5 |       1 |       7 |
|               6 |       1 |       8 |
|               7 |       1 |       9 |
|               8 |       1 |      10 |
|               9 |       1 |      12 |
|              10 |       2 |       3 |
|              11 |       2 |       4 |
|              12 |       2 |       5 |
|              13 |       2 |       6 |
|              14 |       2 |       7 |
|              15 |       2 |       8 |
|              16 |      11 |      12 |
+-----------------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Doesn't your ideal result remove 3 rows (not 2): 1-1-3-2-0?

Comment: @Alan You are correct, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Okay. I corrected my answer slightly. Originally I answered from work and didn't have access to your rextester code. Tested it now and found two syntax errors. Should be good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a UNION of all the combinations that HAVE a person 2, combined with all the combinations thst either have or don't have a person 2, but in any case the first four parts are not in the first list.
Note the CONCAT_WS is needed to tell the difference between 1 + 23 and 12 + 3, which would both concatenate to 123 - this makes them  1~23 and 12~3.

```
(SELECT DISTINCT pt.person_id AS person_1, rt.robot_1 AS robot_1, rt.robot_2 AS target, rp.robot_2 AS robot_2, pt2.person_id AS person_2

FROM robot_partners AS rp

JOIN robot_targets AS rt ON (rp.robot_1 = rt.robot_1)

JOIN robot_targets AS rt2 ON (rt.robot_2 = rt2.robot_2 And rp.robot_2 = rt2.robot_1)

JOIN people AS p ON (p.robot_id = rt.robot_1)

JOIN person_targets AS pt ON (p.person_id = pt.person_id And pt.robot_id = rt.robot_2)

JOIN people AS p2 ON (rt2.robot_1 = p2.robot_id)

JOIN person_targets AS pt2 ON (p2.person_id = pt2.person_id And rt2.robot_2 = pt2.robot_id))

UNION

(SELECT DISTINCT pt.person_id AS person_1, rt.robot_1 AS robot_1, rt.robot_2 AS target, rp.robot_2 AS robot_2, IFNULL(pt2.person_id, 0) AS person_2

FROM robot_partners AS rp

JOIN robot_targets AS rt ON (rp.robot_1 = rt.robot_1)

LEFT JOIN robot_targets AS rt2 ON (rt.robot_2 = rt2.robot_2 And rp.robot_2 = rt2.robot_1)

JOIN people AS p ON (p.robot_id = rt.robot_1)

JOIN person_targets AS pt ON (p.person_id = pt.person_id And pt.robot_id = rt.robot_2)

LEFT JOIN people AS p2 ON (rt2.robot_1 = p2.robot_id)

LEFT JOIN person_targets AS pt2 ON (p2.person_id = pt2.person_id And rt2.robot_2 = pt2.robot_id)

WHERE CONCAT_WS('~',pt.person_id, rt.robot_1, rt.robot_2, rp.robot_2)

    NOT IN 

       (SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT_WS('~',pt.person_id, rt.robot_1, rt.robot_2, rp.robot_2)

       FROM robot_partners AS rp

       JOIN robot_targets AS rt ON (rp.robot_1 = rt.robot_1)

       JOIN robot_targets AS rt2 ON (rt.robot_2 = rt2.robot_2 And rp.robot_2 = rt2.robot_1)

       JOIN people AS p ON (p.robot_id = rt.robot_1)

       JOIN person_targets AS pt ON (p.person_id = pt.person_id And pt.robot_id = rt.robot_2)

       JOIN people AS p2 ON (rt2.robot_1 = p2.robot_id)

       JOIN person_targets AS pt2 ON (p2.person_id = pt2.person_id And rt2.robot_2 = pt2.robot_id))

 )

ORDER BY person_1, robot_1, target, robot_2;
```

Comment: Wow, I was no where near that in my attempts.  I'm surprised at how fast the query actually runs.  Any idea on how well it scales? I would assume it would run into issues with the WHERE CONCAT NOT IN as I dont think it could use an index for that.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Yeah, if all the tables got huge it might slow down. But realize that you are asking the question of 'who can x partner' with for **every** person.  If you were running it from a single player's view, you would add `WHERE p.person_id = 5` in 3 places, and that would keep it from doing so many concatenations.